# Controlling Chrome via VBA with SeleniumBasic

Tags: excel, vba

I have installed SeleniumBasic, and have updated the chromedriver file to the latest version. I have gone into tools> References and activated Selenium Library Type.

At this point, all I am trying to do is  get VBA to open a Chrome browser to google as a starting point. Here is the super complicated macro im trying to fire off:

```
Sub ChromeWebdriver()
  Dim bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
  bot.Start "chrome", "http://www.google.com"
End Sub
```

When I try to run this, I get:

> Run-time error '-2146232576 (80131700)': Automation Error

The research I did on that error message says that there is an incorrect variable. When I hit debug, it highlights:

```
bot.Start "chrome", "http://www.google.com"
```

Does any good Samaritan have advice that can get me started with SeleniumBasic?

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead of `bot.start`

```
driver.Get("http://www.google.com")
```